# Split a raster into 5 pixel x 5 pixel tiles in R

Tags: r, split, raster, tile

Is there a way in R to split a raster file into a grid of tiles that are 5 x 5 pixels, and then be able to plot the tiles back together to view the entire raster as tiles.

I have to do this with approx. 2500 raster files, so some extra advice on doing this with a whole folder of rasters would be awesome too.

But for now I just need a way to do it with the first file.

(I'm a beginner with R so please pardon my lack of knowledge)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to split a raster in 5x5 cell tiles

Example data:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(res=10, vals=1:648)
```

Solution:

```
a <- aggregate(raster(r), 5)
p <- as(a, 'SpatialPolygons')
x <- lapply(seq_along(p), function(i) crop(r, p[i]))
```

`x` is now a list of RasterLayer objects

To plot them (seems an odd approach!), you could do something like this

```
plot(p, border='gray')
z <- lapply(x, function(i) plot(i, add=T, legend=F))
```

Answer (score 1):

There most certainly is :-)

One approach I use quite often is:

```
library(raster)
library(purrr)

r <- raster(ncol = 50, nrow = 50, ext = extent(c(0,50,0,50)))

split_raster <- function(r, nx, ny, buffer = c(0,0)) {

  ext <- extent(r)

  tiles <- vector("list", length = nx * ny)

  n <- 1L

  for (i in seq_len(nx) - 1L) {
    for (j in seq_len(ny) - 1L) {
      x0 <- ext@xmin + i * ((ext@xmax - ext@xmin) / nx) - buffer[1] * xres(r) 
      x1 <- ext@xmin + (i + 1L) * ((ext@xmax - ext@xmin) / nx) + buffer[1] * xres(r) # nolint
      y0 <- ext@ymin + j * ((ext@ymax - ext@ymin) / ny) - buffer[2] * yres(r) # nolint
      y1 <- ext@ymin + (j + 1L) * ((ext@ymax - ext@ymin) / ny) + buffer[2] * yres(r) # nolint
      tiles[[n]] <- extent(x0, x1, y0, y1)
      n <- n + 1L
    }
  }

  crop_tiles <- function(i, e, r) {
    ri <- crop(r, e[[i]])
    crs(ri) <- crs(r)
    return(ri)
  }

  tiles <- purrr::map(seq_along(tiles), function(i) crop_tiles(i, tiles, r)) 

  return(tiles)

}

split_raster(landscape, 10, 10)
```

Depending on the number of tiles and size of your individual raster, you could exchange the purrr::map function with something like:

```
library(raster)
library(furrr)

plan(multisession)

r <- raster(ncol = 50, nrow = 50, ext = extent(c(0,50,0,50)))

split_raster <- function(r, nx, ny, buffer = c(0,0)) {

  [...]

  tiles <- furrr::future_map(seq_along(tiles), function(i) crop_tiles(i, tiles, r)) 

  return(tiles)

}

split_raster(landscape, 10, 10)
```